# How Can I Generate A Visualisation with Multiple Data Series In Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

I have been experimenting with Splunk, trying to emulate some basic functionality from the OSISoft PI Time Series database.

I have two data points that I wish to display trends for over time in order to compare fluctuations between them, specifically power network MW analogue tags.

In PI this is very easy to do, however I am having difficulty figuring out how to do it in Splunk.

How do I achieve this given the field values "SubstationA_T1_MW", & "SubstationA_T2_MW" in the field `Tag`?

The fields involved are `TimeStamp`, `Tag`, `Value`, and `Status`

Edit:

Sample Input and Output listed below:

[image: Sample Input Data]

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: It would help to see samples of the data as well as a mock-up of the desired output.

Comment: @RichG:  Sample input and output added to post :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're going to be most interested in [`timechart`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/timechart) for this

Something along the following lines may get you towards what you're looking for:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp Value=* TimeStamp=* %NStatus=* (Tag=SubstationA_T1_MW OR Tag=SubstationA_T2_MW) earliest=-2h
| eval _time=strptime(TimeStamp,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%N")
| timechart span=15m max(Value) as Value by Tag
```

`timechart` relies on the internal, hidden `_time` field (which is in Unix epoch time) - so if `_time` doesn't match `TimeStamp`, you need the `eval` statement I added to [convert](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.1.3/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions#strptime.28X.2CY.29) from your `TimeStamp` to Unix epoch time in `_time` (which I've assumed is in mm/dd/yyyy format).

Also, go take the free, self-paced [Splunk Fundamentals 1 class](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/training/free-courses/splunk-fundamentals-1.html)

Comment: Thanks Warren, with some minor alteration this is just what I was looking for problem solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

Showing trends over time is done by the `timechart` command.  The command requires times be expressed in epoch form in the `_time` field.  Do that using the `strptime` function.

Of course, this presumes the data is indexed and fields extracted already.

```
index=foo
| eval _time = strptime(TimeStamp, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%3N")
| timechart max(Value) by Tag
```